# Use a condition to set a variable to True

Tags: php

I have a function that checks if a user has the right privileges inside a repertory, and if the user does, i would like it to set a new variable : `getprivileges = true`

```
<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory

function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            $getprivileges = true;
            break;
        }
        scanDirectory($folder, $directory);
    }
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
?>

<?php if ($getprivileges == true): ?>
<p>Permissions granted.<p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I believe the funtion `return` is what I am looking for but I don't really know how to use it.
The last part of the code is just an exemple of what I am aiming to do with my variable.

I'm adding that so far my variable $getprivileges is not defined anywhere else in my code, so maybe I have to give it a default value first ?

Could someone give me some explanations on how i can do this ?

Thanks a lot

**Solution Update from the comments :**

```
<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory
    $getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        scanDirectory($folder, $directory);
    }
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
?>

<?php if ($getprivileges == true): ?>
<p>Permissions granted.<p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: To start, `$getprivileges` is out scope.

Comment: `return true;` or at the end `return false;`  then call `$getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);`

Comment: Set `scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);` to a variable. Then have the function return true or false. Then check that variable, (or just the function call). Also should look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. Notice local and global scopes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions/help ! I updated my post with what I have now, it seems to be working, can you guys confirm this is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this a community wiki because the author already figured out the solution.

---

You are correct that you need to use `return`. By using `return`, you can return some value as the value of the function call, and assign that value to a variable. In your case, you want to return either `true` or `false`.

Then you can set `$getprivileges` like so:

```
$getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
```

Your function should look something like this:

```
function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            // Replaced here.
            return true;
        }
        scanDirectory($folder, $directory);
    }

    // Added here.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah that is indeed what I ended up doing, I see that you added `return false` tho, is it needed ?

Comment: Also isn't break necessary to exit the function once the condition is matched ? Or return does it aswell ?

Comment: @apatik `return` exits the function as well. `break` only exits the loop actually, so you're better off using `return` if you need to exit the entire function. Also, the `return false` at the end ensures that the function will return `false` if it doesn't return `true`. PHP functions by default return null, although null != true so your condition will still pass.